# Android PopupWindow showAtLocation above button

Tags: android, user-interface, popupwindow, gravity

I'm trying to show a PopupWindow immediately above a Button - so that the PopupWindow's bottom edge is aligned with the Button's top edge. I've played around with the various Gravity and getHeight possibilities, but have been unable to get it right.

I would have thought that setting the gravity to Bottom - aligning the PopupWindow to the bottom and then pushing it up by the height of the button would work:

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, button.getHeight());
```

But it only raises the PopupWindow a fraction off the bottom of the screen, covering most of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

**R.style.PopupMenu**

```
  <style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">42dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">16dp</item>
 </style>
```

and apply this style to `PopupMenu` in java code;

```
 Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
 final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this code helps with the location of the PopupMenu in relation to the button. All it seems to do is create a nice animation when it does pop up.  Do you want me to use showAtLocation, or is there some other trick to it?